# Failing to instantiate initial view controller programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, viewcontroller, xctest

I am running an XCTest where I am trying to instantiate a UINavigationController as the initialViewController but it is giving me the following error:

> Could not cast value of type 'ToDo.ItemListViewController'
>   (0x10cce7208) to 'UINavigationController' (0x10f93ced8)

The ItemListViewController is embedded within the Navigation Controller, and "Is Initial View Controller" is selected for the Navigation Controller. This is exactly how I'm instructed to do this by a tutorial... perhaps I have another setting interfering? Here is my code

```
func test_InitialViewController_IsItemListViewController() {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let navigationController =
        storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as! UINavigationController
    let rootViewController = navigationController.viewControllers[0]
    XCTAssertTrue(rootViewController is ItemListViewController)
}
```

Screenshot for reference:

[image]

Comment: That's very odd. I'm able to make a similar structure, but get the results you expect. This leads me to believe that something may be strangely wrong with your storyboard. What happens if you delete the navigation controller and re-embed the Item List VC in a new navigation controller?

Comment: I’ve tried that a number of times with the same result

Comment: Looks good. Are you using Xcode 9 or 10?

Comment: @dasdom XCode 9.2

Comment: This looks like it’s from my book. Can you compress the project and send to dasdom@swiftandpainless.com. Then I’ll have a look.

Comment: Absolutely! Coming right up. Thanks for the help.